# How to access a view of an included library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, view, null, findviewbyid

I am using a color picker library from [THIS LINK](https://github.com/Pes8/android-material-color-picker-dialog)

It works well, and I want to be able to access a certain element from the [XML](https://github.com/Pes8/android-material-color-picker-dialog/blob/master/library/src/main/res/layout-v21/materialcolorpicker__layout_color_picker.xml). Here is the code I am interested in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ColorPicker">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/colorView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"/> 
     <!--...-->
```

I am trying to access the item with `colorView` id. In java code, I have this:

```
ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(additionPractice.this, 0, 0, 0);
```

I expected to use
        `colorPicker.findViewById(R.id.colorView)`, but this is `null`. Is there a way to access this element? I can provide more code if you want, and there is a lot of info in the Github link. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You're probably trying to find it too early. Move that `findViewById()` call to right after the `show()` call.

Comment: I just went through the source, and it looks like it wouldn't cause any problems to call `create()` right after instantiation, so if you'd rather, you should be able to do: `ColorPicker colorPicker = ...;`, `colorPicker.create();`, `View colorView = colorPicker.findViewById(R.id.colorView);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
colorPicker.show();
View colorView = colorPicker.findViewById(R.id.colorView);
```

I just try this ,It worked!

Comment: I think he want access the element in the java code. The xml is in the library,  please click [here](https://github.com/Pes8/android-material-color-picker-dialog/blob/master/library/src/main/res/layout-v21/materialcolorpicker__layout_color_picker.xml) to view it .

Answer (score 1):

You can take that ColorPicker file from library and make your custom class and you can use it the way you want.